# Running Flutter/Dart commands in batch script halts execution

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, batch-file, command-prompt

Say I have a batch script with the following commands:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

When I run it, the batch script halts executing after the first command. See the attached image below for reference.

[image]

**[Only executed first flutter command]**

In general, the batch script keeps on running command after command but for flutter and dart commands, that doesn't seem to be the case. How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: The `flutter` command on Windows is itself a batch file, and one batch file calling another must use `call`.

Comment: I think the suggested solution by @jamesdlin is working.